# mysql search string in table ignoring links

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am trying to search the wordpress posts in my database, that match a string.

However i want to get the rows that have the matching words in them as a plain text, but not the ones that have the word embedded inside a link.

For example, if a post has the following text in 'wp_posts' table of database:

```
'This is a Test page: <a href="http://localhost/test-page">About Test</a>'.
```

And i search for the word 'about' in my custom query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content like '%about%';
```

so i am getting the above post as the result.
Is there a way i can ignore the posts that have the search string embedded inside a link, and fetch other posts which have the search string as part of a normal string?

I tried a REGEX query, with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content REGEXP '[[:<:]]about[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: is the about case sensitive? about vs About ... SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE lower(post_content) like '%about%';

Comment: The case sensitivity does not matter here. The results can include anything.

Comment: what datatype is the post_content?

Comment: post_content is of datatype 'longtext'

Comment: mysql version is: 5.1.36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this :

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content LIKE '%about%' AND post_content NOT REGEXP '>[^>]*about[^<]*<';
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot another %.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_content REGEXP '^[^<>]+about';
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2530a9/4)

Comment: I also wanted to filter 'about' from: 'This is about Test page: <a href="http://localhost/test-page">about Test here</a>'. So the solution by Yejing works in this case. May be you have to include 'NOT' before 'REGEXP' in your query

Comment: Ok, Any how someone helped.

Answer (score 0):

in sqlfiddle it works fine!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1697/2

**Create script**

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
(
    test longtext
);

INSERT INTO supportContacts(test) VALUES ('This is a Test page: <a href="http://localhost/test-page">About Test</a>')
```

**Select**

```
select * from supportContacts where test like '%about%'
```

Comment: Actually i already tried the given query, but i don't want the results which contain the search string as part of a link.